# Opencart product images are not displayed, "src(unknown)"

Tags: php, html, image, opencart

I am creating test environment for my opencart installation. I downloaded all files and imported database too from live server. I am using XAMPP local server.
All functions are working properly. But the product images are not displayed. Other images like logo, icons are displayed and images in admin panel are also displayed. Just product images are not visible. When I inspect the image tag on browser the src field is set to unknown.

```
<img src(unknown) alt="Sony Xperia L1 4G 16 GB Mobile Phone | Pink" title="Sony Xperia L1 4G 16 GB Mobile Phone | Pink" class="img-responsive">
```

I tried on different browser but the issue is still same.

Comment: in you config.php check path for
"define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/image/');" or whatever your image folder path is

Comment: I was using relative path i.e. just /image
Thanks this solved the issue and there are other constants like DIR_SYSTEM,DIR_APPLICATION
For all of them I have to set absolute path as you mentioned ? And please post your answer , I will accept and upvote

Comment: yeah you can try doing that if you face any issue :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In config.php check the path for **DIR_IMAGE**.
You are using **relative path**.

It should be

```
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/image/');
```

For all the CONSTANTS **absolute path** should be used while working on local server and Opencart.
So other CONSTANTS will also change as

```
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project_name/system/storage/upload/');
```

Comment: please add it should respect caps.. as in path from explorer.. it doesn't work with small "c:/.." instead of "C:/..." (tested w764 xampp 7.4.7) ty